# Making firebase storage public for reading and writing on android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am new to firebase storage. Can anyone tell me how to make the storage files public for reading and writing?. The default code provided by firebase is given below. What changes should I make ?

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/image-view-b1cf5.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 54, accepted):

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/secure-files#understand_rules) explains that if no rule expression is provided, the rule evaluates to true:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/image-view-b1cf5.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      // Allow access by all users
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: That doesn't remind us that our storage is public, as it does in firebase database. Are you sure this is the only way of making it public?

Comment: @ashay:  If you need a reminder, add a comment to the rule.

Answer (score 86):

FYI: if you want public read only.

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/image-view-b1cf5.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
        allow read;
        allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Good one; could not find how to setup d/t rules for read and write on their doc.

Answer (score 4):

```
// Anyone can read or write to the bucket, even non-users of your app.
// Because it is shared with Google App Engine, this will also make
// files uploaded via GAE public.
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Just Removing

> if request.auth != null;

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/image-view-b1cf5.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      // Allow access by all users
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Happy Coding

Answer (score 0):

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: What (except bad indentation) does this answer have that the previous answers don't?

Answer (score 0):

Removing the authentication condition should work.

Comment: This is not true.

Comment: If you don't change auto generated code, it is public, and can be accessed by the link it provides.

Comment: This is not true. It is protected by default (only authenticated users). Check the docs out: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/

Comment: Here's the excerpt from the docs I posted above: **For example, the default Storage Security Rules require Firebase Authentication in order to perform any read or write operations on all files.**

Comment: I made a cross platform data transfer from a set of android devices to a windows pc. For android devices, authentication was used but for pc version, no authentication was used by me and it works smoothly.

Comment: I think you should delete this answer now since it's misleading.